# I need an example of a function such that the derivative minus x is the same as the original function

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm curious if there is a function F(x) whose derivative f(x) is the same as F(x) + x. I tried to make one myself by adding things to e^x with no success. the function was mentioned in Question 21 of the academic assessment conducted in Korea in March 2021. It didn't mention the specific function, and the question was solvable without it. But I'm curious what that function would be. The test was for high schoolers, so I think the function will not wander outside the context of Korean High School Math curriculum.(The only Transcendental function taught in Korea's high school math curriculum is logarithmic function, trigonometric functions, and exponential function)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+f%27%28x%29+%3D+f%28x%29+%2B+x

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Solve differential equation $f'(x)=f(x)+x$

Comment: $F(x)=x+1$ for one but there are many others. If you need to find the general solution, learn about first order linear differential equations.

Comment: @bof if F(x) is x + 1, then its derivative would be 1. F(x) + x = 2x +1 isn't 1. I think you may have misread the question. thank you for the answer, though.

Comment: -1 vote? You guys are way to mean to new people. The guy has a legitimate question; he's not trying to get you to do his homework, he is having curious thoughts about the world of math. Why are you guys always so keen to shut people down like this? There's enough gate-keeping going on with math, guys. Must we?

Comment: As a high-schooler, is it maybe possible that he's never heard of a differential equation, and this was a really cool way for him to get introduced to the idea? I think walking him through the standard method of solving for differential equations could have been a lot more fruitful for everyone.

Comment: Oops, wrong  sign, should be $F(x)=-x-1$.

Answer (score 2):

The question is to solve the first order ODE $f'(x)-f(x)=x$. We can use a trick called [integrating factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor): note that $f'(x)e^{-x}-f(x)e^{-x} = (f(x)e^{-x})'$. Thus, multiplying the ODE on both sides by $e^{-x}$, we find the equivalent form
$$ (f(x) e^{-x})' = xe^{-x}$$
Integrating both sides (leaving the details to you) gives the general solution
$f(x) e^{-x} = -xe^{-x} - e^{-x} +C$, i.e.
$$ f(x) = -x -1 + Ce^x.$$
Here, $C$ is an arbitrary constant. $C=0$ gives bof's solution in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

Suppose $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...$. Then $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}-x=a_1+(2a_2-1)x+3a_3x^2+...$

If these functions are to be equal, then we must have the following:

$$a_0=a_1$$
$$a_1=2a_2-1$$
$$a_2=3a_3$$
$$a_3=4a_4$$
$$a_4=5a_5$$

And so on. Now we can solve for the various $a_n$ in terms of $a_0$, like so:

$$a_0=a_1\Longrightarrow a_2=\frac{a_0+1}{2}$$
$$a_2=3a_3\Longrightarrow a_3=\frac{a_0+1}{6}$$
$$a_3=4a_4\Longrightarrow a_4=\frac{a_0+1}{24}$$

In general, for $n\geq 2$, we have that $a_n=\frac{a_0+1}{n!}$. If your function $F(x)$ is given by an infinite series, then as long as its coefficients follow that rule, it will be equal to its derivative minus $x$.

But what if it's *not* an infinite series? Well, that's the thing: a function given by finitely many terms in powers of $x$ is exactly the same thing as an infinite series, only with finitely many non-zero coefficients. And when you take the derivative of such a series, the degree of the term with the "last" nonzero coefficient, so to speak, reduces by one. In other words, quadratic functions become linear, cubics become quadratic, quartics become cubic and so on.

The only way of getting around this problem of diminishing degrees for finite series is if the coefficients of terms of degree $2$ or higher are $0$ in the first place! And by the conditions we derived, that can only occur if $a_0=-1$, for then $a_n=\frac{-1+1}{n!}=\frac{0}{n!}=0$. And given that $a_1$ must be equal to $a_0$, this means that $F(x)=-1-x$ is the only such function. I invite you to differentiate it and subtract $x$ to verify that it indeed is a solution.

### Addendum

As I mentioned previously, $F(x)=-1-x$ is the only *finite* solution, but what about the infinite series solution? We already defined the rule that $a_n$ must follow if the function is to conform to the condition, but is there a closed form for it? You bet there is! Here's how to find it...

Recap: we discovered that, for the infinite series solution, we must have that $F(x)=a_0+a_0x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{a_0+1}{n!}x^n$. Note that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{a_0+1}{n!}x^n$ can be rewritten as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_0+1}{n!}x^n -((a_0+1)+(a_0+1)x)$

Since $a_0+1$ does not depend on $n$, we can factor it out of the summation; what we are left with in that case is $(a_0+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}-((a_0+1)+(a_0+1)x)$. Of course, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ has the very simple closed form of $e^x$. Making this substitution and distributing the minus sign, what we have is the following:

$F(x)=a_0+a_0x+(a_0+1)e^x-(a_0+1)-(a_0+1)x=a_0+a_0x+(a_0+1)e^x-a_0-1-a_0x-x=-1-x+(a_0+1)e^x$

Letting $c=a_0+1$, we end up with $F(x)=-1-x+ce^x$. This is the solution we get if all of the infinitely many coefficients are *not* equal to $0$.

Comment: [+1] It's good to recall this [series solution](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Calculus_(OpenStax)/17%3A_Second-Order_Differential_Equations/17.04%3A_Series_Solutions_of_Differential_Equations) method which work also for linear ODEs of any order.